# EditText Floating Label в DialogFragment с каcтомным View

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Делаю так, получаю поле без подсказки совсем:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_category,container,false);
    TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ILetAddCategory);
    editText = (EditText)textInputLayout.findViewById(R.id.etAddCategory) ;
    textInputLayout.setHint("Floating Label");

return view;
```

В XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ILetAddCategory"
    android:hint="Floating Label"

    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etAddCategory"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `hint` проставить для EditText а не для TextInputLayout

Comment: Не помогает. Тот же самый код работает с EditText в активити, и мы находим  TextInputLayout без посредства view

Comment: @xebeche в таком случае попробуйте обратиться через активити в фрагмент, геттером засетить хинт программно.

Comment: C hint_om все в порядке, его даже можно не сетить динамически ведь android:hint="Floating Label" это и есть и это должно работать, так как сам класс TextInputLayout все делает в коробке. 
Поэтому думаю чисто человекческая ошибка - проверить стиль, бекграунд цвета совпадает с текстом, DialogFragment не из AppCompat либы, чтот тип того.

Comment: @Shwarz Andrei Да, спасибо. была путаница с наследованием!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C hint_om все в порядке, его даже можно не сетить динамически ведь `android:hint="Floating Label"` это и есть и это должно работать, так как сам класс TextInputLayout все делает в коробке.

Поэтому следует проверить, что DialogFragment из `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`